# How do I modify an array and retrieve the same modified values of an array outside a loop within a single iteration in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

The idea is to loop across the diceValues array and within each single iteration, store the current item in loop into an outside array named "firstSplitDiceValues". The codeblock below is a much simplified form to outline the challenge.

So in other words, every iteration should keep building the length of the firstSplitDiceValues and at the same time this firstSplitDiceValues should be pushed as value in another array named "moves".

```
let firstSplitDiceValues = [];
const tokens = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
const diceValues = [1, 3, 4, 6];
const moves = [];

for (let diceValue=0; diceValue < diceValues.length; diceValue++) {
    firstSplitDiceValues[diceValue] = diceValues[diceValue];  // [1]
     
    moves.push([
       {
           [tokens[diceValue]]: firstSplitDiceValues
       }
    ]);
}
console.log(moves);

// What I expect:
// Moves array should contain:
[
    [{"A": [1]}],
    [{"B": [1, 3]}],
    [{"C": [1, 3, 4]}],
    [{"D": [1, 3, 4, 6]}]
]

// Actual results:
// Moves array only shows final expected value on all iterations
[
    [{"A": [1, 3, 4, 6]}],
    [{"B": [1, 3, 4, 6]}],
    [{"C": [1, 3, 4, 6]}],
    [{"D": [1, 3, 4, 6]}]
]

// What I expect:
// Moves array should contain:

[
    [{"A": [1]}],
    [{"B": [1, 3]}],
    [{"C": [1, 3, 4]}],
    [{"D": [1, 3, 4, 6]}]
]
```

Comment: You're pushing the same array in memory to `moves` for each iteration. I don't see currently in your logic why you'd expect the first array in `moves` to be `[3, 4, 6]` though. According to your description, you're supposed to push to `firstSplitDiceValues` every iteration and then push that array to moves, so, shouldn't it be `{'A': [1]}`, as on the first iteration you would've only seen element `1`

Comment: Or is your real goal to ignore the current index from `diceValues` and push that version into each object. That's what your expected result makes it seem like you want to do. You've also mentioned pushng into `firstSplitDiceValues`, what is the expected result of that supposed to look like, or does that not matter?

Comment: Hi Nick parsons, thank you. I've made the edit on my expected results. Again this is what I expect:

// Moves array should contain:

`[
    [{"A": [1]}],
    [{"B": [1, 3]}],
    [{"C": [1, 3, 4]}],
    [{"D": [1, 3, 4, 6]}]
]
`

I do not intend to ignore the current index from diceValues but instead use every index to update the firstSplitDiceValues from diceValues array using the same index

Comment: Thanks, and is `firstSplitDiceValues` expected to have anything?

Comment: Yes @NickParsons. It starts out empty, but builds it's length by 1 for each iteration. 

I have actually found a solution but new to StackOverflow and realised direct comments can't easily contain code blocks.

So I will reply under my original post and make a mention of you. I suspect that's the conventional way it's done here, or any better way please? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do that, but please take a look at the existing answers and see if they answer your question. I’ve also added an answer below with multiple approaches. If your answer is different than what’s already there, feel free to add it and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays (and objects) are not copied when you assign them to another variable, or to an object's property. Instead the variable/property points to the original array. Because you mutate the `firstSplitDiceValues` array by assigning a new value `firstSplitDiceValues[diceValue] = diceValues[diceValue];`, the original array, and everything that points to it would show all the values.

Use `Array.map()` to iterate `tokens`, and slice the `diceValues` according to the current index (`i`). Slicing an array creates a new array.

```js
const tokens = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
const diceValues = [1, 3, 4, 6];

const moves = tokens.map((t, i) => ({ [t]: diceValues.slice(0, i + 1) }));

console.log(moves);
```

Comment: Succinct yet informative. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing the same array firstSplitDiceValues in memory to moves for each iteration. Instead you want to create a new array for each move and populate it with appropriate values. You can use slice() to achieve the result. Here is the updated code.

```js
const firstSplitDiceValues = [];
const tokens = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
const diceValues = [1, 3, 4, 6];
const moves = [];

for (let diceValue = 0; diceValue < diceValues.length; diceValue++) {
    const splitDiceValues = diceValues.slice(); // Create a shallow copy of diceValues
    const token = tokens[diceValue];
    splitDiceValues.splice(diceValue, 1); // Remove the current dice value from splitDiceValues
    moves.push([{ [token]: splitDiceValues }]);
}

console.log(moves);
```

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thank you very much. You came quite close to the solution I wanted. You only slightly misconstrued my original question.

I have worked with your solution and made the necessary tweak to arrive at the final solution. Have a look: 

``

Comment: Gad to know that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you only ever create on `firstSplitDiceValues` array when your program initially starts, that means that there's only one `firstSplitDiceValues` array in memory. As a result, when you change this array at each iteration, you're really changing the same array in memory, and so the array you pushed previously will also update. To get your expected result, the easiest thing to do would be to create a new array at each iteration. That way you're creating a unique array in memory for each iteration and so it won't impact the other references you've pushed into `moves` already. The easiest way to create an array holding `n` items from `diceValues` is to use `diceValues.slice(0, n)`, which gives you the first `n` items from `diceValues` as a new array. With this approach, you don't need `firstSplitDiceValues` anymore:

```js
const tokens = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
const diceValues = [1, 3, 4, 6];
const moves = [];

for (let i = 0; i < diceValues.length; i++) {
    const diceValuesSubset = diceValues.slice(0, i + 1);
     
    moves.push([
       {
           [tokens[i]]: diceValuesSubset
       }
    ]);
}
console.log(moves);
```

This can be written more declaratively with `.map()`:

```js
const tokens = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
const diceValues = [1, 3, 4, 6];
const moves = diceValues.map((_, i) => ({
  [tokens[i]]: diceValues.slice(0, i + 1)
}));
console.log(moves);
```

If you need to update `firstSplitDiceValues`, then I would suggest you `.push()` to it each iteration, and then call `.slice()` on it to get a make a unique copy in memory to avoid changing that version of the array on subsequent iterations:

```js
const firstSplitDiceValues = [];
const tokens = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
const diceValues = [1, 3, 4, 6];
const moves = [];

for (let i = 0; i < diceValues.length; i++) {
  firstSplitDiceValues.push(diceValues[i]);
  moves.push([
    {
      [tokens[i]]: firstSplitDiceValues.slice()
    }
  ]);
}
console.log(moves);
console.log(firstSplitDiceValues); // same as values as diceValues
```